# Is there a way to use Python or Linux to create a directory of folders and word docs out of a .txt file?

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to create a directory of folders and then word documents out of lines in a .txt file, and I am using Python. Below is an example of what my .txt file looks like.

```
Main Topic
    Sub Topic 1
        Folder 1
            Item 1
            Item 2
            Item 3
        Folder 2
            Item 4
            Item 5
            Item 6
    Sub Topic 2
        Folder 3
            Item 7
            Item 8
            Item 9
```

So all the main topics, sub topics and folders need to be folders, then each item is to be a word document. Each word doc item is at varying depths (maybe 4 folders deep, maybe 6) and there's 2800 lines approximately. I have worked out how to create the word docs in theory, I just haven't been able to get up to that part yet.

My main problem is being able to change which file path I am in when I iterate through the list and create a new folder, it needs to be in the correct directory. Sub Topic 1 in Main Topic, but Folder 3 in Sub Topic 2, etc.

I have been playing around with the OS module/library in Python, but the dynamic nature of the file path is proving difficult. I also have a quite basic understanding of Linux, but am learning about it currently anyway, so I'd be open to using Linux to solve this too. I know that you can create folders and files easier on there.

My thinking so far has been that, for each iteration of the list, I will need to keep track of a number of previous item variables, such as the name, the number of indents/tabs, the file path used, etc, but I'm not sure.

Comment: what must each word document contain, or would you expect them to all be blank word docs?

Comment: Are you locked into the text file format, or can you switch to e.g. yaml?

Comment: @rv.kvetch It will contain a list that actually goes one level deeper than the "Items" I displayed. So under each Item 1, Item 2, etc is a list of lets call them Content 1, Content 2, etc, and they are indented one more time than the items.

Comment: @thebjorn I'm open to whatever will help me achieve the end result I'm looking for. I had to Google what YAML was haha but I could get on board with that if you have an idea

Comment: I daresay YAML is a good idea here as it'll simplify the part where you need to parse the text file lines as a dictionary object. Any good YAML parser can already convert that to a `dict` object, since YAML is very similar in syntax to what you have above.

Comment: @rv.kvetch I'll look into it and see what I can do with it, sounds promising though. Thanks.

Comment: It's always a good idea to not write your own parsers when you don't have to (and this is from a guy who enjoys writing parsers). YAML isn't the fastest format, and it certainly has its problem areas, but simple YAML is easy to write and easy to understand - and it is universally well supported.

Comment: Why was this closed? The problem description is very clear. It wouldn't be made any clearer with any code I can think of that the OP could have added, and code is not required if the question is otherwise OK - which this one is.

Comment: probably it was close because you didn't show your code and FULL error message. Stackoverflow is not place to write all code for you.

Answer (score 1):

The yaml version of your input file would look like:

```
Main Topic:
    Sub Topic 1:
        Folder 1:
            - Item 1
            - Item 2
            - Item 3
        Folder 2:
            - Item 4
            - Item 5
            - Item 6
    Sub Topic 2:
        Folder 3:
            - Item 7
            - Item 8
            - Item 9
```

and can be parsed with (yaml from PyYAML, available on pypi):

```
import yaml
with open('structure.yaml') as fp:
    structure = yaml.load(fp)
```

I'm reading it from a string for ease of debugging:

```
import os
import yaml

structure = yaml.load("""
Main Topic:
    Sub Topic 1:
        Folder 1:
            - Item 1
            - Item 2
            - Item 3
        Folder 2:
            - Item 4
            - Item 5
            - Item 6
    Sub Topic 2:
        Folder 3:
            - Item 7
            - Item 8
            - Item 9
""")
```

`structure` is now a nested dict. An easy way to see what it contains is to use the json module to print it out:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(structure, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

which outputs

```
{
    "Main Topic": {
        "Sub Topic 1": {
            "Folder 1": [
                "Item 1",
                "Item 2",
                "Item 3"
            ],
            "Folder 2": [
                "Item 4",
                "Item 5",
                "Item 6"
            ]
        },
        "Sub Topic 2": {
            "Folder 3": [
                "Item 7",
                "Item 8",
                "Item 9"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

now all we have to do is walk this data structure and create directories or files.

First a couple of helper functions

```
def indent(n, *args):
    "same as print, but indented n levels"
    print('    '*n, end='')
    print(*args)


def create_word_document(fname, level):
    "you'll have to implement this yourself ;-)"
    indent(level, "CREATE:WORD:DOCUMENT:", fname)
    open(fname, 'w').write('word document')
```

Using a recursive function we only need to look at the level we're currently working at:

```
def create(structure, level=0):
    if isinstance(structure, dict):
        curdir = os.getcwd()
        for directory, content in structure.items():
            indent(level, "MAKEDIR:", directory)
            os.mkdir(directory)
            indent(level, "CD:", directory)
            os.chdir(directory)

            create(content, level=level+1)  # recursive call

            indent(level, "CD:BACK (..)")
            os.chdir(curdir)
    else: # if it is not a dict, it is a list
        for fname in structure:
            create_word_document(fname, level)

create(structure)
```

All the indent calls are just an aid to debugging.

It will print out what the function does:

```
MAKEDIR: Main Topic
CD: Main Topic
    MAKEDIR: Sub Topic 1
    CD: Sub Topic 1
        MAKEDIR: Folder 2
        CD: Folder 2
            CREATE:WORD:DOCUMENT: Item 4
            CREATE:WORD:DOCUMENT: Item 5
            CREATE:WORD:DOCUMENT: Item 6
        CD:BACK (..)
        MAKEDIR: Folder 1
        CD: Folder 1
            CREATE:WORD:DOCUMENT: Item 1
            CREATE:WORD:DOCUMENT: Item 2
            CREATE:WORD:DOCUMENT: Item 3
        CD:BACK (..)
    CD:BACK (..)
    MAKEDIR: Sub Topic 2
    CD: Sub Topic 2
        MAKEDIR: Folder 3
        CD: Folder 3
            CREATE:WORD:DOCUMENT: Item 7
            CREATE:WORD:DOCUMENT: Item 8
            CREATE:WORD:DOCUMENT: Item 9
        CD:BACK (..)
    CD:BACK (..)
CD:BACK (..)
```

and confirmed by the tree command:

```
c:\stmp> c:\windows\system32\tree.com /F "Main Topic"
Folder PATH listing for volume Windows
Volume serial number is ...
C:\STMP\MAIN TOPIC
├───Sub Topic 1
│   ├───Folder 1
│   │       Item 1
│   │       Item 2
│   │       Item 3
│   │
│   └───Folder 2
│           Item 4
│           Item 5
│           Item 6
│
└───Sub Topic 2
    └───Folder 3
            Item 7
            Item 8
            Item 9
```